# What is going on with my form upload image using ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new user in creating web using rails. When i am creating my web, I got the problem in uploading image using carierwave and ajax. When i submit value with uploading an image, everyhing is working but my image could not appended to my html view. It is different when i submit value without uploading an image. Everything is working and my view is appearing like i want. Anyone here, could help me to solve my problem....???

```
$( "#mytable" ).prepend( "<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list/model') %>" );
```

Code above writing for respond javascript.

```
<tr id="<%= model.id %>">
   <td><%= image_tag model.images.find_by_id(model.column_img).picture.nil? ? Image.new.picture.default_url : model.images.find_by_id(model.column_img).picture.url %></td>
</tr>
```

Code above is partial code using in my index model

```
    <table class="table table-hover" id="mytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% unless (@models.empty? ) %>
        <% @models.each do |model| %>
           <%= render partial: "list/model", locals: {model: model} %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Code above is my code for appearing list my model.

I try using remoti for handling ajax but not function.

Thanks...

Comment: Are you able to get image path properly from this code `model.images.find_by_id(model.column_img).picture.url` try run this on console.

Comment: Yes..i get image_path properly on console....
For additional explanation :
When i submit value without uploading image, my view is appearing like i want and image appearing is my default image because image value is nill.

Comment: yes I have seen that in your partial. On first time page load are you able to see all uploaded images properly ?

Comment: Yes...on first time page load, i can see all uploaded images properly. When i create new or edit, to create or update,(Both of them using {remote: true}),list is not appended but data success be created or updated, with or without image.